# How to design a simple login system in C?

Tags: c, authentication

I am new to C. I try to develop a simple login system as part of another program. And if the user writes a wrong password 3 times, the program exits. when I write the right password at the first time, it goes well. But when I write a wrong one then tries to write the right one at the second or third one, it still considers it a wrong one.

```
void login ()
{
  int i;
  char password[12] = "mohammed3336";
  char trypassword[50];
  for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
  {
    scanf ("%s", &trypassword);
    if (strcmp (trypassword, password) == 0)
    {
      printf ("login is successful!\n\n");
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      if (i == 2)
      {
          exit (0);
      }
      printf ("password is wrong, try again (trial %d of 3)\n", i+1);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This `char password[12] = "mohammed3336";` does not end with a `NUL` terminator (there wasn't room), therefore you cannot pass it to string handling functions. It is *undefined behaviour* and it happens to work or it happens to not work. Please use `char password[] = "mohammed3336";` and then the compiler will assign a proper string.

Comment: ... but you also have a buffer overflow exploit waiting to happen (and the incorrect use of `&`): please restrict the input with `scanf ("%49s", trypassword);`

Comment: Thanks. I thought I no longer need the null terminator in the newer versions of C!

Comment: I understand the formatting. But why is the use of & is wrong here? @WeatherVane

Comment: AFAIK you never had to specify the length of the string when assigning a literal to it this way.

Comment: The definition of a C string is an array of `char` terminated by `0`. When initialising a string like, the `NUL` is only placed if there was room.

Comment: And the `&` is not needed because `char[]` is *already* an address, to the first character in the array.

Comment: The point of specifying the length of the array is when you want it to be *longer* than the initialising data (for example so you can concatenate another string).

Comment: I see. Thanks for all this information.

Comment: @MohammedElbagoury *'Thanks. I thought I no longer need the null terminator in the newer versions of C! '* who did tell you thar

Comment: my professor in the university

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char username[15];
    char password[12];


    printf("Enter your username:\n");
    scanf("%s",&username);

    printf("Enter your password:\n");
    scanf("%s",&password);

    if(strcmp(username,"chaitu")==0){
        if(strcmp(password,"123")==0){

        printf("\nWelcome.Login Success!");


        }else{
    printf("\nwrong password");
}
    }else{
    printf("\nUser doesn't exist");
}





    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to provide an explanation? What changed?